# Cannot add TMS async components to win32 firemonkey program

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tms, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a firemonkey app targeted only at win32. I want to add the tms async serial communications component.  When I do so and try to build it gets upset trying to compile the tms source code. It is non-trivial to change the tms source code.

Where is it picking up the library path to the source code? If I remove that path will it use the existing `.dcu` files and work?  Is there any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't think there is _delphi Berlin10.22_

Comment: There is no such Delphi version as *Berlin 10.22*, and the VCL tag does not apply when you're asking about Firemonkey.

Answer (score 0):

What was catching me is that even though I had removed the directories from the options search path,, I had one of the tms rtl files still open in the ide. As a precaution, I also went and moved the tms source files elsewhere...

The form compiled and the components work.